# New to php and need to format a php page from html statement

Tags: html, html-table, templating

My problem is the page shows a vertical line of options.  I want to put them into a 4 column table to display instead of just down lhs of page.  The code I want to change is as follows:

```
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>{LOOP: JOBTYPE}
    IF("{JOBTYPE.parent_id}"!="0"){&nbsp; {:IF}
    IF("{JOBTYPE.catcount}"=="0"){<input type="checkbox" name="jobtype[{JOBTYPE.id}]"  value="{JOBTYPE.id}" {JOBTYPE.selected}>{JOBTYPE.title}<br>{:IF}
  IF("{JOBTYPE.catcount}"!="0"){<strong>{JOBTYPE.title}</strong><br>{:IF}
  {/LOOP: JOBTYPE}</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see I have another column there and can split cell further but I would like the job list to be displayed across the page not vertically.

Comment: I think its ugly pseudo-code.

Comment: What template system is this?  I don't think this question has much at all to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create 4 columns using the following HTML template:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>........</td><td>........</td><td>........</td><td>........</td></tr>
<tr><td>........</td><td>........</td><td>........</td><td>........</td></tr>
.
.
.
</table>
```